# Detect a paste event in a react-native-material-textfield

Tags: javascript, react-native, textfield, clipboard

I want to paste into a `react-native-material-textfield`, but do something based on the pasted content (i.e. if the pasted content is a link, style it accordingly). However, in order to do this I need to know when something has been pasted into the `OutlinedTextField`. I am not sure how to listen for a paste event. The Clipboard does not really help here because all it does it `set/get` content, not tell me if some arbitrary content has been pasted.

**The minimal sample code**

```
import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard';
import {
  OutlinedTextField,
} from 'react-native-material-textfield';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  handleOnPaste = (content) => {
    alert('paste detected! content: '.concat(content));
  }

  handleOnChangeText = async (content) => {
    if (content === '') return;
    const copiedContent = await Clipboard.getString();
    
    if (copiedContent === '') return;
    const isPasted = content.includes(copiedContent);
    if (isPasted) this.handleOnPaste(content);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <OutlinedTextField
                ref={this.ac_bankRef}
                keyboardType='numeric'
                autoCapitalize='none'
                autoCorrect={false}
                enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={false}
                onChangeText={this.handleOnChangeText} 
                 returnKeyType='done'
                label='Bank(2)*'
                
                maxLength={2}
                inputContainerStyle={{height:height>800?48:40,marginTop:10}}
                contentInset={{label:1,input:12}}
                baseColor={'#D4D4D4'}
                lineWidth = {1}              
/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above sample code `const isPasted = content.includes(copiedContent);` is always return false when using `OutlinedTextField` but in normal `TextInput` of react native it is working fine.

Please help me to resolve problem . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by removing `maxLength={2}` property of `OutlinedTextField` . After removing property i am able to detect copy paste event.